# how to AES ECB mode with 20byte key

Tags: c#, javascript, php

how to decrypt "AES" "ECB mode"   with 20byte key ( can't change key ) encrypted text "**debac58d0bc8526339678667bca923e15a7106a0c16c8148bd1468cefad57762ccf53a4a780bc27748c5583a02c41dee**" ,  key "**qwertyuioplkjhgfdsaz**" , plain text "http://www.hellohello.com/hellohello.asp" .. any javascript, php, C# will help

Comment: you are looking for 160 bit just replace KeySize=160 and it should work.

Comment: "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm." Error when i use 160bit key, this site is decrypting well working good "http://aes.online-domain-tools.com" but m not able to decrypt

Comment: That site decrypt good you say look at bottom `AES` `16, 24 or 32` bytes `128, 192 or 256` bits, it also don't support 20 byte but how it decrypt good? maybe you need 24 byte.

Comment: the test case provided in question only got decrypted in that site no where else i have tried C#, JavaScript but not working at all. that site was even decrypting with 20 byte key. i dun know how ????

Comment: I made solution that works in C# feel free to look at answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here is the solution in C#, it only supports any Key key size up to 32 bytes and as low as 0 bytes key.

Ideone sample: https://ideone.com/XONRBf

Screenshot of the solution:

[image: answer]

C# Source code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String cryptedText = "debac58d0bc8526339678667bca923e15a7106a0c16c8148bd1468cefad57762ccf53a4a780bc27748c5583a02c41dee";
            String key = "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsaz";
            Console.WriteLine("Crypted Text = " + cryptedText);
            Console.WriteLine("Key = " + key);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted = " + Decrypt(cryptedText, key));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string toDecrypt, string key)
        {
            byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); // AES-256 key
            PadToMultipleOf(ref keyArray, 8);
            //byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
            byte[] toEncryptArray = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(toDecrypt);

            RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
            rDel.KeySize = (keyArray.Length * 8);
            rDel.Key = keyArray;          // in bits
            rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx
            rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.None;  // better lang support
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        }

        public static void PadToMultipleOf(ref byte[] src, int pad)
        {
            int len = (src.Length + pad - 1) / pad * pad;
            Array.Resize(ref src, len);
        }

        public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
        {
            if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
            }

            byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
            for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
            {
                string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
                HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            return HexAsBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Life saver! Tried more complex algorithms without luck. Thanks.